# Move PDF files to specific folders as per list in excel

Tags: vba

Experts.,

I have an Excel file Containing list of Folder names and a list of file names.

Now i have a Folder with all PDF files , with same names as per list in excel.,

I need to make new Folders with names as per list of folder names in excel., and then transfer the pdf files in this folder as per the list in excel.

Comment: Please post what you have done so far. Kindly follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You might want to google the "File System Object" - you'll find lots of examples that will help you